# What does gcc mean here?

Tags: c, gcc, cpu-cache

I am studying a thesis. This paper describes a side channel attack. It measures the `cache miss rate` when there is only the attacker's code, and the cache miss rate when other programs and the attack code run on the same core as interference. I found that the `cache miss rate` can be obtained through `perf`. But after thinking about it for a long time, I can't fully understand what this interference program is.
The following are the original words in the paper.

> we also show the results when there is only the sender process running on the physical core (denoted by sender only) and the results with the sender sharing the physical core with a benign gcc workload (denoted by sender & gcc). When there is only the sender process, it has the smallest L1 miss rate. When it is sharing the core with a benign program, the benign program, e.g., the gcc, will cause contention in the cache.

what does the interference program mentioned here refer to? Is it a benign c code, or is it a gcc library when compiling c code with gcc?

If the interference is to run the gcc library to compile the c code, the gcc compiles the c code in an instant. How can we make it run for a long time? This may be a very basic question, but I haven't figured it out after thinking about it for a long time.
The URL of the paper is:
https://caslab.csl.yale.edu/publications/xiong2020leaking.pdf
Thank you to everyone who is willing to provide suggestions.

Comment: The word "interference" does not  occur in the quoted text. Please clarify.

Comment: the gcc, will cause contention in the cache. I think the meaning of this sentence is as interference.  I added a link to the paper. My purpose is to reproduce this example, so I don’t have the smallest reproducible example.

Comment: BTW, [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) can be used or built as a cross-compiler: you can run it on a different computer than the one which would run the executable produced by it. So I don't understand your question.

Comment: Thanks. But this is exactly my problem. Look at the italics above. This is the original words in the paper, I actually want to know what gcc is said there? How to use it?

Comment: When you explain you post a link and then edit and delete the link, you make all comments no longer relevant. Don't do that.

Comment: There is no italics anymore. Sorry for confusing you so much, but the quote formatting I applied really is more appropriate.

Comment: IMHO this is a fallacy of the paper. The author should have clearly expressed what a "benign gcc workload" is and how he achieves it. We now have to guess it is the gnu c compiler. But we don't know for sure. So to really know, you'll have to e-mail the author.

Comment: @JHBonarius: “gcc” is the well-known name of the GNU Compiler Collection. It does not require any explanation in the paper.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Well, I disagree. According to [this](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/GCC) and [this](https://www.abbreviations.com/GCC), "GCC" can mean a number of things. The best we can do is assume from the context of the paper that the author is talking about the GNU compiler. But that's only our best guess... Furthermore, a paper should (try to) be as complete as possible, in order for others to reproduce the results, thus the author should be specific on what a "benign gcc workload" is.

Comment: @JHBonarius: The term in the paper is “gcc”, not “GCC”, and we know the Gulf Corporation Council does not execute as a workload on a processor, and neither does Glendale Community College, Global Climate Change, Groupware Competence Center, and so on. I have no doubt the intended audience of the paper knows what was intended.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ok, lets assume it is. But is it just using `gcc` command? That could be an alias for clang... And what version of gcc? Is the optimizer running? etc etc. (offtopic I liked "Golf Cart Conspiracy"  )

Answer (score 0):

“gcc” refers to the primary command of the [GNU Compiler Collection](https://gcc.gnu.org). There are several reasons the run time of gcc might not be too short for the work in the paper:

1. The short running time of gcc may suffice for the work in the paper.
2. You may experience gcc as taking a short time for the programs you use it for, but it may take much longer for longer programs in more complicated languages.
3. gcc can be asked to operate on many source files in a single command.
4. gcc may be run repeatedly during the work in the paper.

You may be accustomed to running programs on a computer used exclusively by you. Commonly, in environments where side channel attacks are a concern, programs are run on “server” systems concurrently by multiple users. Such systems may be continuously busy. (This is not to exclude such attacks being a concern in a system normally used only by a single person, where, aside from the software desired by the rightful user, some software is executing at the instigation of a malicious person.)

Comment: Do you mean I can increase the time by writing a make command in a loop?  In that case, how can I bind it to run on a certain core? For example, can taskset 0x6 make command do it?